# Convert an xml response to json

Tags: xml, json, node.js

I am making a `POST` request with `node.js`, which sends out an `xml`request and returns some result `xml`.

The resulting response when I run `req.write( body );` is in `XML`, but I would like to convert it to `JavaScript` through [xml2json](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js).

I have the following, but this only turns the request into JSON, not the response.

```
parseString(body, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

How can I turn the `req.write(body);` response into JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Isn't `result` within the `parseString` closure the JSON result of the conversion from XML?  If that's the case, then couldn't you just put `req.write(result)` within the closure?

Comment: @zero298 `result` as I am getting it back is the JSON that has been converted from XML. The problem is that the `result` is actually the request...I'm not sure how to access the `result` XML

Comment: Can you post the code that makes the request as well?

Comment: Please put that in your question as an edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `parseString` function, as defined in [xml2js docs](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js), inside of res.on, as in the following:

```
var req = http.request( postRequest, function( res )    {
    console.log( res.statusCode );
    var buffer = "";
    res.on( "data", function( data ) { buffer = buffer + data; } );
    res.on( "end", function( data ) { 
        parseString(buffer, function (err, result) {
            console.dir(JSON.stringify(result));
            inspect(result)
        });
    } );
});
```

Thus, when you call req.write(body) it will trigger `parseString` at the end of the response.